# Weird drive popped up randomly

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, virus

I just had a random drive pop up as I was doing a defrag on my hard drives (windows 8.1) and I have no idea what it is or what it does. It's called: `\\?\Volume{5a1f49...` what is it and is it harmful to my laptop?

Comment: might be the recovery disk

Comment: ok. so how do i optimize it?

Comment: optimize what? and for what?

Comment: It says that it is 90% fragmented and I've been trying to optimize the "\\?\Volume{5a1f49..." and it does nothing. how might I do that?

Comment: I doubt a recovery disc is fragmented. you might not have enough free space to properly defrag... assuming your using a magnetic disc

Comment: i have a 1 terabit hard drive and it is fragmented according to my computer.

Comment: why is this on security btw? its clearly a generic SE question. (I flagged it to be moved)

Comment: That's where my brother told me to put it and I'm sorry but I'm not savvy when it comes to windows 8.1. and just asked what it was, if it was harmful and how i can optimize it.

Comment: I would suggest you reword your question. add what you know, have done, and what your working with. than what you fear or suspect.

Answer (score 1):

#### It's called: \?\Volume{5a1f49... what is it and is it harmful to my laptop?

`\\?\Volume{5a1f49...` is a mounted volume.

`mountvol` will display a list of mounted volumes.

Example:

Here you can see I have some volumes that are not currently mounted (removable USB drives), shown by `*** NO MOUNT POINTS ***` instead of a drive letter.

```
C:\test>mountvol
Creates, deletes, or lists a volume mount point.

...

Possible values for VolumeName along with current mount points are:

    \\?\Volume{fba39dd9-9356-11e4-8b45-806e6f6e6963}\
        *** NO MOUNT POINTS ***

    \\?\Volume{d1a5461a-9369-11e4-b7ab-ccaf78b24c0a}\
        E:\

    \\?\Volume{fba39dda-9356-11e4-8b45-806e6f6e6963}\
        C:\

    \\?\Volume{fba39dd8-9356-11e4-8b45-806e6f6e6963}\
        *** NO MOUNT POINTS ***

    \\?\Volume{fba39ddd-9356-11e4-8b45-806e6f6e6963}\
        D:\
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [mountvol](http://ss64.com/nt/mountvol.html) - Link volumes without requiring a drive letter. Create, delete or list a volume mount point.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is a partition on your hard drive that does not have a label on a GPT formatted disk, Windows will show it as `\\?\Volume{*insert GUID*}`.

It's not uncommon to have partitions without labels on Windows 8.1 computers. Some manufacturers will create partitions involved with their recovery software and leave them label-less. There are a lot of complaints on the web by people who have upgraded to Windows 8.1. You may want to ask your computer's manufacturer.

But ultimately, having an unnamed partition on your hard drive is not harmful to your laptop as a fact by itself. You can see how large it is in disk management (Windows Key + X, select disk management) to see if it's wasting a lot of space on your drive.

That is to say, its existence doesn't really say very much. It could be a utility installed from your manufacturer. It could be something involved with your recovery software. It could be from an OS upgrade or disk transfer. It could be the result of nefarious hackers or a virus.

Comment: I believe all partitions use *`\\?\Volume{insert GUID}`* internally. That is, that's the native format of the Volume Manager. When you see something like *`C:\\`*, that's a presentation detail provided by a UI component.